# Minimize inputs by loading values in MATLAB functions

Tags: matlab, optimization, input

In MATLAB is it be better (as far as optimization is concerned):

1)To have a function "foo" with a lot of inputs that come from the outputs from other functions

or

2)Save at the end of the functions the results to a results.mat file and load it in the "foo" function and minimize its inputs this way?

Comment: or 3) use `cell` or `struct` to collect and/or group data and minimize argument count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

almost always: option 1.

As option 2 depends on file IO, and thus one write and one read to/from a hard disk, SSD or similar, it will likely lose out against keeping variables in RAM. Moreover, if you pass arguments to a function, and that function only *reads* them, no explicit copies of that variable are made. This is not true for the `.mat` file solution, as something that *you already have in memory* will be explicitly copied onto an ***extremely*** slow device (HDD, SSD), and then again read back into memory from the ***extremely*** slow device, just to save on a few input arguments.

So, unless you're working with big data sets and your variables give you out-of-memory errors, keep everything in RAM as much as possible.

You can minimize argument count by simply collecting data in a container data type. MATLAB has `cell` and `struct` for this purpose (or `classdef`, if you include value classes). You can transform this:

```
[outarg1, outarg2] = function(arg1, arg2, arg3,...)
```

into

```
[outarg1, outarg2] = function(S)
```

where

```
S = struct(...
    'arg1', function1(X),...
    'arg2', function2(X,Y,Z),...
    'arg3', function3(X,Z),...
    %// etc.
);
```

or

```
S = {
    function1(X)
    function2(X,Y,Z)
    function3(X,Z)
    %// etc.
}
```

or similar. Or you can make use of the special `cell`/functions called `varargin/nargin` and `varargout/nargout`:

```
varargout = function(varargin)

    % rename input arguments
    arg1 = varargin{1};
    arg2 = varargin{2};
    %// etc.

    % assign all output arguments in one go
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = deal(outargs{:}));

end % function
```

You can read more about all these things by typing `help <thing>` on the MATLAB command prompt. For example,

```
help cell
```

will give you a wealth of information on what a `cell` is and how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I think using global variables is a better way to optimize memory and processing requirements.
you can use keyword `global`.

Comment: Whatever I have read until now and everybody says to avoid them in almost any case. Especially in big programs with a lot of functions etc.

Comment: This is not true; globals do not provide better performance than explicit passing of the arguments. Moreover, [global variables are usually strongly discouraged](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad) in any well-structured program. Not because of performance reasons, but they tend to make code far more opaque and "spaghettified" in the long run than other paradigms. Also, in the context of multi-threading and distributed computing, global variables are usually pretty tricky to work with.